# Python: Type Errors

Tags: python

This is not the real logic of my program, just a simplified version of it. Any help will be really appreciated.

My question is I am maintaining a state like this:

```
next_state = (state,self.visited_states)
# where self.visited_states = (False, False)
# I want the state to be in this form ((1,1),(False, False))
```

I need to change the boolean values to True when one of the state is visited. So I was trying something like this:

```
self.visited_states[0] = True.
```

I got an error as follows:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tuple are immutable type you can't modify. In expression:

```
self.visited_states[0] = True.
        ^
        should not be a tuple
```

If you wants to change it take `visited_states` as list.

```
self.visited_states = [False, False]
```